# Problem in calculating residue in analytic number theory of a function derived from Partition Function generated by Euler Infinite Product

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, residue-calculus

I am self studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number theory and I have a doubt in calculating residue in Chapter -5 , page 95 .

The partition function p(n) generated by Euler 's Infinite Product

Define 
F(x) =  $ \sum_{n=0} ^\infty  p(n) x^n $ , p(0) = 1 .

> Here x[n+1] means x is being raised to power n+1 .

If 0<|x|<1 , then dividing both sides by $ x^{n+1} $ 
 $\frac {F(x) } { x^{n+1}} $ = $\sum_{k=0} ^\infty  \frac { p(k)  x^k } { x^{n+}} $ for each n greater than or equal to 0.

I understand that last series is Laurent expansion of $ \frac { F(x) }  { x^{n+1}} $ in the punctured disk 0<|x|<1 .

Can somebody please give a proof of this

> This function has a pole at x=0 with residue p(n) .

I am not able to prove how this residue is p(n) . Can somebody please help.

Comment: You meant $$\frac{F(x)}{x^{n+1}}$$ has a pole at $x=0$ of residue the coefficient of $x^n$ in $F$'s Taylor series, this holds for all analytic functions.

Comment: @reuns yes. But I don't know mathjax program of x raised to power (n+1) . When I wrote it , it was ambiguous. But I meant exactly the expression which you have written. Can you please tell how residue is p(n).

Comment: @reuns writing x raised to power n is easy ,as I have to enclose x^n between dollar signs but if I enclose x^(n+1) in dollars I get  $x^(n+1) $  , which is not clearly x raised to power n+1 . So, I used [ ] . Can you tell how to write x  raised to power n+1 .

Comment: @reuns I hope problem is clear now. Can you please answer it if you got some spare time

Comment: Click on edit/improve in the other questions to see mathjax code. What do you want more than what I said ? The residue at $0$ of a meromorphic function is the coef of $x^{-1}$ in its Laurent expansion near $x=0$.

Comment: @reuns you are absolutely right, I was confused. I knew this result from complex analysis but I became confused after looking at series.

Comment: @reuns how to give bounty to you for this question as bounties can't be awarded to comments? What should I do now?

Comment: @reuns Would you be willing to promote your comment to an answer so that the bounty can be awarded?